# MessagingCenter message not being received when data is passed from Android to PCL

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to send back data from MainActivity to a PCL view. When I send a message without data, it receives it. But when I try to pass a string back with it, the code is never reached.

In MainActivity:

```
if(data != null)
            {

                MessagingCenter.Send<object, string>(this, data, "MapIntentReceived");
                MessagingCenter.Send<object>(this, "MapIntentReceived");

            }
```

In PCL:

```
            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object, string>(this, "MapIntentReceived",
                async (sender, roomString) =>
                {   //his code is not reached
                    await SearchForRooms(roomString);
                });

            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object>(this, "MapIntentReceived",
                async (sender) =>
                {   //this code is reached
                    await SearchForRooms("blah");
                });
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To send the message with argument, include the Type generic parameter and the value of the argument in the Send method call.

```
MessagingCenter.Send<MainPage, string> (this, "MapIntentReceived", data);
```

To pass an argument with the message, specify the argument Type in the Subscribe generic arguments and in the Action signature.

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MainPage, string> (this, "MapIntentReceived", (sender, arg) => {
    await SearchForRooms(arg);
});
```

For unsubscribe

```
MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<MainPage, string> (this, "MapIntentReceived");
```

Comment: The message is coming from MainActivity, not MainPage, which is why I'm passing a generic object back. But you pointed out I was passing back the data string in the wrong parameter spot, which fixed my problem. Thanks!

Comment: @WillNasby, you can use any object instead of MainPage.

Comment: how you can use any object ? shouldnt sender and subscriber type match? if you use MainActivity on Send and MainPage on Subscribe? will this work?